# MySQL service on Windows resets password on every start

Tags: mysql, windows-services

I have a local MySQL 8.0.21 server for development purpose. It's configured as Windows service. After first setup everything works fine and my **root** password fits well, but as soon as I stop and start this service my password becomes invalid.

Does anybody know where the problem is?

Comment: Do you actually have 2 MySQL servers running?

Comment: How do you know, that the password becomes invalid?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah. I run MySQL 5.7 on 3306 and MySQL 8.0 on 3307